# Error when using MBXMapKit in xcode

Tags: ios7, mapkit, mapbox

I'm building an iOS7 app and we are trying to implement a custom MapBox map using the MBXMapKit. We have successfully done this on a mockup, but our final code is returning the following error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBXMapView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in EnginesViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no clue on where to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are not linking an i386 (i.e., Mac simulator) version of MBXMapKit into your project. Check the architecture build settings for your Xcode project to make sure you cover all the device architectures (`armv*`) and the Macs you will test on (`i386` and/or `x86_64`).

Comment: in checking our mockup that is working, it looks like all settings within Build Settings/Architectures match our current project. Can you advise which specific line I need to edit?

Comment: Can you possible include a screenshot of any of your target build settings from Xcode that mention architecture?